# CSS Styling Angular Multiselect Dropdown

Tags: css, angular, multi-select

Trying to adjust the height of this multiselect and have tried a few things, with no success.  Below are what I tried.

```
ss-multiselect-dropdown > div.btn-group > ul.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 180px !important;
}

.multiselect-parent .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 180px !important;
}
```

This is what I want to style.

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [settings]="multiSelectSettings" [options]="preferredFundingStatusOptions" [texts]="preferredFundingStatusTexts" [(ngModel)]="preferredFundingStatusSelection" name="preferredFundingStatusSelection"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: Where are you inserting this piece of css: in the styles.css from the app' root folder or in the .css from a component?

Comment: I tried both the styles.css and the .css of component